# Broken image links even though links are correct and images exist

Tags: images

I recently migrated my site from BlueHost to Siteground. The uploads folder was not migrated properly, so I had to ftp many of the folders manually. Most of the images are showing up properly now, however, some of them are still not showing. For example [on this post](https://madhouseheaven.com/hiking-on-the-coast-of-santo-antao) most of the photos are not there. But there is one that is. When I go into my file manager however, I see that the photo IS THERE.

For example, the first photograph which is broken, links to "[https://i0.wp.com/madhouseheaven.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Santo-Antão-021-1024x579.jpg?resize=1024%2C579&ssl=1](https://i0.wp.com/madhouseheaven.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Santo-Ant%C3%A3o-021-1024x579.jpg?resize=1024%2C579&ssl=1)"

When I look inside the folder, the image is there.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution was to delete the files in the month folder (it doesn't work when I delete the entire folder and put it back again for some reason) and add all the individual files back into the folder.